# Use MobileME to host multiple domain names

Tags: mobileme, websites, iweb

I have a quick and simple question, is there any possible way to host more than one domain name from a single MobileME account? I am using iWeb11 and already have purchased two domain names and configured one of them with ME, this works fine but I would just like to be sure that I don't need to buy an additional ME account if it isn't absolutely necessary. Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each account only allows one domain name to be listed. To get full separation, you will need either a family pack (for 5 accounts) or multiple main accounts on MobileMe.

Since iWeb does allow multiple sites, perhaps you could use forwarding or redirect for the subsequent custom domains. Making a CNAME pointing www to your mobile me entry point is the cleanest way to pass traffic, but there are other ways if you don't mind the hassle and exposing your mobile me hosting when the redirect shows the URL where you are hosting.

Most web-savvy people can tell a domain is hosted from mobile me even if you use the "offical" one domain per account method - it just is easier to keep your mobile me name from the address bar of most web browsers that way.

Comment: And since new sign-ups are closed, we'll have to see what happens with iCloud this fall but you will be able to keep your Mobile Me until June 30, 2012 and have lots of time to decide what to do once the new service goes live.

Comment: I suspect that the Web hosting part of MobileMe will be killed once iCloud arrives and MobileMe is shut down. There's ample precedent for Apple to kill services they think no longer make sense: think iCards. There's been no mention of the fate of iDisk, either, and Steve specifically made fun of the idea of "a hard drive in the sky." For us longtime Apple watchers, when Steve mocks something, it's going to go away sooner or later.

Comment: Apple has made it very clear that June 30, 2012 is the last day MobileMe will work. It's in the two sentence summary at the top of http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4597 - given that, I would be highly surprised if web forwarding didn't work up until the end. I agree with your sentiments - just we don't have to guess on the end date for MobileMe as we currently know it.